# How to create custom login provider like third party login provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jwt

I have an Angular app and two web APIs.

One is used for authentication and other for the rest of the processing.

Users will log in to the authentication provider and the other web API will send token received from Angular app to the authentication API.

The authentication API will return the object.

The other API can use attributes like [Authorize].

How can I do this?

I want to create something like this:
[image: external-authentication-services]

I have read this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services) but it doesn't include information about Custom login provider.

Comment: You should take a look at IdentityServer ( https://identityserver.io/ )

Comment: I saved the same JWT signing key on both the APIs. And used the JWT authentication. It did the trick. The same token can be used for authentication on both the APIs. I am now able to use [Authorize] in my controllers.